# How do I integrate a codepen?

Tags: javascript

EDIT: Answered own question with some fiddling around

Bit of a newbie question but sure someone here can help:

I am simply rubbish with JS but am learning on my feet.

I have created a simple codepen and want to use it in certain custom pages on my wordpress site.

The question is - how and where do I add the JS portion so that my site recognises it?

Also, at the bottom of the HTML portion is says:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

....which I assume will need to be added somewhere too?

Thanks.

Comment: Stylesheets and scripts are necessary to your pen to work correctly. and wordpress have it's own way to inject script/style files called enqueuing. but in this case jQuery is already loaded by wordpress so you don't need to include jquery

Comment: I see, so I can live without that line.

So the css portion also seems to reference: 
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

I added this to my child theme functions.php as enqueue and it has broken my site.  Man it seems like it should be such a simple task :/

Comment: Actually, it is.. it'll be even more simple once you get the hang of it. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

All sorted.

My theme actually had a section for custom javascript in the theme options.

I added the code there and used the enqueue for the bootstrap - all working fine now.